# Flashing messages to user

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm looking for a appengine library that lets me push messages for a user.

I'm aware that there was a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4927211/1442147) for this. But the library the user was suggesting has been looking for a maintainer for three years and lot of their documentation has turned into dead links.

Webapp2 has [something close](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) to this. But this requires me to manually get get_flashes and provide them to template in every single view. I'm looking something where and I can set a flash and loop through them in the template as I wish.

Comment: Any recommendation would need to be in the context of 1. your chosen language, to what web framework your using.

Comment: I thought webapp2 was the default. Oh well I added the tag.

Comment: It might be, but django is also included, and I have been using appengine since 2008 and never used either ;-)  So I wont' assume anything.

Comment: A quick search with google for "webapp2 flash message" highlights the flash functionality included in webapp2.  Is this not adequate

Comment: I want to add this functionality without boilerplate code in every view. I probably should have explained this.

Comment: well what templating are you using. Most have a main template that you either inherit from or extend, and you can put the code there that renders the flash.  It is important to be quite specific when you ask questions, otherwise the process turns into 20 questions, as people try to guess what you are after or just ignore the question and don't bother. That and the functionality could be inherited from  a base view.